# implementing a network fuzzer over a vnc server?

Tags: networking, fuzzer, fuzz-testing

i want to implement a network fuzzer over a vnc server as a final year project .  I want to code both the fuzzer and the vnc server from the scratch . Can i know how feasible it is ? And some good tutorials on it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.securiteam.com/tools/6D0020KNFA.html) is a fuzzer for VNC.    [Peach](http://peachfuzzer.com/) is an excellent fuzzing platform that can fuzz [servers](http://peachfuzzer.com/TutorialNetworkServer).  You can also test remote locations using [AgentsMonitors](http://peachfuzzer.com/AgentsMonitors).